# Stata counting substring

Tags: count, substring, stata

My table looks like this:

```
ID         AQ_ATC     amountATC
.       "A05"                 1
123     "A05AA02"          2525
234     "A05AA02"          2525
991     "A05AD39"           190
.       "C10"                 1
441     "C10AA11"          4330
229     "C10AA22"          3100
.       "C05AA"               1
441     "C05AA03"           130
```

The count for the full 8-character `AQ_ATC` codes is already correct.
The shorter codes are unique in the table and are substrings of the complete 8-character codes (they represent the first x characters).
What I am looking for is the count of the appearances of the shorter codes throughout the entire table. 
For example in this case the resulting table would be

```
ID         AQ_ATC     amountATC
.       "A05"              2715       <-- 2525 + 190
123     "A05AA02"          2525
234     "A05AA02"          2525
991     "A05AD39"           190
.       "C10"              7430       <-- 4330 + 3100
441     "C10AA11"          4330
229     "C10AA22"          3100
.       "C05AA"             130       <-- 130
441     "C05AA03"           130
```

The partial codes do not overlap, by what I mean that if there is `"C05"` there wont be another partial code `"C05A1`".

I created the amountATC column using

```
bysort ATC: egen amountATC = total(AQ_ATC==AQ_ATC)
```

I attempted recycling the code that I had received yesterday but failed in doing so.
My attempt looks like this:

```
levelsof AQ_ATC, local(ATCvals) 

quietly foreach y in AQ_ATC { 
local i = 0
quietly foreach x of local ATCvals { 
    if strpos(`y', `"`x'"') == 1{
    local i = `i'+1
    replace amountATC = `i'
    }
 }
}
```

My idea was to use a counter "i" and increase it by 1 everytime the an `AQ_ATC` starts with another `AQ_ATC` code. Then I write "i" into `amountATC` and after I iterated over the entire table for my `AQ_ATC`, I will have an "i"-value that will be equal to the amount of occurences of the substring. Then I reset "i" to 0 and continue with the next `AQ_ATC`.
At least thats how I intended for it to work, what it did in the end is set all `amountATC`-values to 1.

I also attempted looking into different egen-functions such as noccur and moss, but my connection keeps timing out when I attempt to install the packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems as if you come from another language and you insist in using loops when not strictly necessary. Stata does many things without explicit loops, precisely because commands already apply to all observations.

One way is:

```
clear
set more off

input ///
ID         str15 AQ_ATC      amountATC
.       "A05"                 1
123     "A05AA02"          2525
234     "A05AA02"          2525
991     "A05AD39"           190
.       "C10"                 1
441     "C10AA11"          4330
229     "C10AA22"          3100
.       "C05AA"               1
441     "C05AA03"           130
end

*----- what you want -----

sort AQ_ATC ID
gen grou = sum(missing(ID))

bysort grou AQ_ATC: gen tosum = amountATC if _n == 1 & !missing(ID)
by grou: egen s = total(tosum)

replace amountATC = s if missing(ID)

list, sepby(grou)
```

### Edit

With your edit the same principles apply. Below code that adjusts to your change and slightly changes the code (one line less):

```
*----- what you want -----

sort AQ_ATC
gen grou = sum(missing(ID))

bysort grou: gen s = sum(amountATC) if AQ_ATC != AQ_ATC[_n+1] & !missing(ID)
by grou: replace amountATC = s[_N] if missing(ID)
```

More efficient should be:

```
<snip>

bysort grou: gen s = sum(amountATC) if AQ_ATC != AQ_ATC[_n+1]
by grou: replace amountATC = s[_N] - 1 if missing(ID)
```

Some comments:

1. `sort` is a very handy command. If you sort the data by `AQ_ATC` they are arranged in such a way that the short (sub)strings are placed before corresponding long strings.
2. The `by:` prefix is fundamental and very helpful, and I noticed you can use it after defining appropriate groups. I created the groups taking advantage of the fact that all short (sub)strings have a `missing(ID)`.
3. Then (by the groups just defined) you only want to add up one value (observation) per `amountATC`. That's what the condition `if AQ_ATC != AQ_ATC[_n+1]` does.
4. Finally, `replace` back into your original variable. I would usually `generate` a copy and work with that, so my original variable doesn't suffer.

An excellent read for the `by:` prefix is [Speaking Stata: How to move step by: step](http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=pr0004), by Nick Cox.

### Edit2

Yet another slightly different way:

```
*----- what you want -----

sort AQ_ATC
gen grou = sum(missing(ID))

egen t = tag(grou AQ_ATC)
bysort grou: gen s = sum(amountATC * t)

by grou: replace amountATC = s[_N] - 1 if missing(ID)
```

Comment: I just saw that I once named my row "amountATC" and once "countATC". Those are supposed to be the same tables, I'll fix the original post.

Comment: The same principles apply.

Comment: Thank you very much! I made an error which resulted in your code not working for me at first, but I found it and your code works perfectly :).
If you don't mind, would you try to explain your thought process to me when writing this? It might be a strange request, but oftentimes I don't know how to approach the tables and perhaps it would give me some insight.
And yes, I do come from other languages and try to aplly what I learned there to Stata, but so far that has not been too succesful, haha.

Comment: I added some comments. I hope they help.

Comment: See also http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/programming/if-command-versus-if-qualifier/index.html