# Using a local in Stata to change values of variable

Tags: stata

I've got a variable `countrycode` in my dataset that uses ISO numeric codes (basically 3 numbers) to identify which country each observation is from. However, to merge with another dataset, I need to change these country codes to ISO alpha values (3 letters).

I have a csv file (ISOcodes.csv) that matches up the numeric codes and the alpha codes; it looks like this:

```
num,name,alpha  
004,Afghanistan,AFG  
248,Åland Islands,ALA  
008,Albania,ALB   
...
```

Here's my attempted solution:

```
insheet using ISOcodes.csv

* Create variables ISOnum_1, ISOnum_2, etc. and ISOalpha_1, ISOalpha_2, etc. 
* ISOnum_1 and ISOalpha_1 should refer to the same country
local N = _N
forvalues x = 1 (1) `N' {
    local ISOnum_`x' = num[`x']
    local ISOalpha_`x' = num[`x']
}

clear 
insheet using maindataset.csv

* Replace all numeric values in `countrycode` with the corresponding `alpha` values
recast countrycode str3
foreach x = 1 (1) `N' {
    replace countrycode = ISOalpha_`x' if countrycode == ISOnum_`x'
}

list countrycode
```

However, I haven't even been able to create the locals; when I run this, I get the error "num not allowed" as soon as I try to assign the first local. Any ideas on what's going wrong here? Any problems I should anticipate in the next section? I am very new to Stata.

Also, when I clear out the ISOcodes.csv dataset to import my main dataset, will I lose all the locals I just assigned?

Comment: Cross-posted at statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/… Cross-posting on other forums is not out of order, but it would be courteous to tell us about it. See e.g. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/why-is-cross-posting-wrong-on-an-external-site for discussion. Statalist are quite explicit about doing that in reverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the loops. You want to use the `merge` command. Next an example:

```
clear

*----- example data sets -----

// crosswalk file

input ///
str3 numiso str15 name str3 alpha
004 "afghanistan" "afg"
248 "aland islands" "ala"
008 "albania" "alb"
end

tempfile crossfile
save "`crossfile'"

list

more

// main data set

clear

input ///
str3 numiso str15 name gdp
004 "afghanistan" 476
248 "aland islands" 644
008 "albania" 500
end

list

*----- what you want -----

merge 1:1 numiso using "`crossfile'"

list
```

You probably need to adjust details because you are not precise with your data set descriptions. See `help merge`.

This has been coming up lately: explicit loops are not as common in Stata as in other languages because, by default, commands will affect all observations (from 1 to _N). See for example [Stata counting substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27344146/stata-counting-substring).

Answer (score 1):

@Roberto Ferrer rightly explains that looping over observations is not a good strategy here, or indeed generally in Stata, and gives an alternative solution.

That leaves unexplained what's wrong with your code.

Oddly, or not, I can't see what produces the error you report, but there are several others.

1. On import, the leading zeros in `num` will get stripped unless you import them explicitly as string variables. Stata will read 012 as 12.
2. At the outset, you create both sets of local macros using values of `num`. One set should use `num`; the other should use `alpha`.
3. In essence, local macros are **not** variables in Stata. See [this post](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2008-08/msg01258.html) for a discussion of that and other common confusions.

This is more than correcting terminology: your code errs because you are referring to local macros as if they were variables, and that won't work.

You are using the notation to evaluate local macros, but that has to be carried all the way.

4. You need double quotation marks to make clear that you want a literal string evaluation when using the `num` and `alpha` values.
5. You also confuse `foreach` and `forvalues`.

Your final loop stands as at

```
foreach x = 1 (1) `N' {
    replace countrycode = ISOalpha_`x' if countrycode == ISOnum_`x'
}
```

That should be more like

```
forval x = 1(1)`N' {
    replace countrycode = "`ISOalpha_`x''" if countrycode == "`ISOnum_`x''"  
}
```

UPDATE: At a guess, the error reported arose **because in fact you used quite different syntax from what you said**.

In the Statalist posting, you report syntax such as

```
  local ISOnum_`x' : num[`x']
```

which is indeed illegal.